# List of all collections in mongo database in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

how can I get a list of all the collections in the database?

- database - mongodb;
- language - java;
- ide - eclipse;

Comment: doesn't `show collections` in mogodb's shell do that ?

Comment: @tonio - OP asked specifically about Java.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getting A List Of Collections
Each database has zero or more collections. You can retrieve a list of them from the db (and print out any that are there) :

```
Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

for (String s : colls) {
System.out.println(s);
}
```

***Edit*** : As suggested in @Andrew's answer, updated java client uses this :

```
/**
 * Gets the names of all the collections in this database.
 *
 * @return an iterable containing all the names of all the collections in this database
 */
MongoIterable<String> listCollectionNames();
```

and getting the iterable collection based on the document type :

```
/**
 * Finds all the collections in this database.
 *
 * @param resultClass the class to decode each document into
 * @param <TResult>   the target document type of the iterable.
 * @return the list collections iterable interface
 * @mongodb.driver.manual reference/command/listCollections listCollections
 */
<TResult> ListCollectionsIterable<TResult> listCollections(Class<TResult> resultClass);
```

Answer (score 9):

In MongoDB 3, it's now `db.listCollectionNames()`. There's also `db.listCollections()`

See the [API Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html#listCollectionNames--).