# How to retrieve collections name using mongodb api Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, iterator, cursor

I'm trying to retrieve the collections name in my program
i created this method for this

```
        public static LinkedList<String> getListOfCollections() {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)) {
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db name");
            MongoIterable<String> mList = db.listCollectionNames();
               for (String string : mList) { // ---- crash here ----
            list.add(string);
        }
    } catch (MongoException | ClassCastException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception occurred while insert Value using getListOfCollections  ");
    }
    return list;
}
```

but for a reason it keep crashing
its also crashed when I used:

```
 MongoCursor<String> tmp = mList.iterator();
```

p.s-
the uri is working and i'm capable of inserting Documents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all collections in mongo database in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971329/list-of-all-collections-in-mongo-database-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

apparently my IP has changed and I couldn't access the database hence I couldn't retrieve the collections (and insert data).

lesson - make sure your IP is correct in the MongoDB -Network access.
BTW, this method works!